# Submit a form that is saved in a string (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms

I have a HTML form a string variable.
e.g: there are below string in `FormBody` variable string.

```
<form id='paymentUTLfrm' action='...' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='CardAcqID' value='131211234234667' />
  <input type='hidden' name='AmountTrans' value='1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='ORDERID' value='1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='TerminalID' value='1723429902234254' />
  <input type='hidden' name='TimeStamp' value='1282408234231473657' />
  <input type='hidden' name='FP' value='56-85-2E-A6-F4-4B-7F-AD-17-E1-D9-97-D5-40-62' />
  <input type='hidden' name='RedirectURL' value='http://localhost:1903/Service1.asmx?op=MelliSale' />
  <input type='hidden' name='MerchantAdditionalData' value='' />
  <input type='hidden' name='Version' value='3.22' />
</form>
```

Now I wanna submit it via ASP.NET and C# !!!
Could you please guide me how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this page 
[How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

or do pablo answer

Answer (score 1):

You need an HttpClient in C#. You can take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303436) MS support document with some help on how to do that or you can just use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class.

With that Http Client, you will have to implement the `POST` HTTP command to send your data with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. That encoded data will contain each variable have in your string. To get their values, you will have to parse it.